# Request FREE source codes for the SpringBoard Home Screen

Tags: ios4

My client requests to have the 4 x 4 application icons styles on iPhone Home Screen, which the application can be re-arranged and paging is enabled, in my application development

Is there any one know whether that module is free for download and use ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Three20](http://three20.info/)'s [launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher).